# Periodic Error getting while rendering in in REACTJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js, rendering, typeerror

Getting "Cannot read property 'value' of undefined" error, sometimes code is getting rendered fine and output is showing as expected. Could infer that,the "value" is not loaded to the attribute "fill" before it gets rendered. How do I correct it to render only if the the values are loaded into component

```
import React, { useMemo, useState, useEffect, useCallback } from "react";
import { geoPath, geoMercator, geoIdentity } from "d3-geo";
import * as d3 from "d3";
const Map = ({ stateGeographies, geoData, statecode, plotdata }) => {
  const [circledata, setCircleData] = useState([]);
  const width = 750;
  const height = 450;
  const projection = geoMercator().fitSize([width, height], {
    type: "FeatureCollection",
    features: stateGeographies
  });
  const path = useMemo(() => {
    if (!geoData) return null;
    return geoPath(geoIdentity());
  }, [geoData]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const features = () => {
      return stateGeographies.map((feature) => {
        const district = feature.properties.district;
        const state = feature.properties.st_nm;
        const obj = Object.assign({}, feature);
        const val = plotdata.filter((p) => {
          const datavalue = p.place === district ? p.value : null;
          return datavalue;
        });
        obj.id = `${statecode}-${state}${district ? "-" + district : ""}`;
        obj.value = val;
        return obj;
      });
    };
    setCircleData(features);
  }, [statecode, stateGeographies, plotdata]);
  var color = d3
    .scaleThreshold()
    .domain([2000, 5000, 8000, 10000, 15000])
    .range(["#FFA07A", "#FA8072", "#CD5C5C", "#DC143C", "#FF0000"]);

  return (
    <svg width={1000} height={600} viewBox="0 0 800 450">
      <g className="states">
        {circledata.map((d, i) => (
          <path
            key={`path-${i}`}
            d={geoPath().projection(projection)(d)}
            className="state"
            fill={color(!d.value ? 0 : d.value[0].value)}
            /*fill={function (d) {
            return color([d.value[0].value]);
          }}*/
          />
        ))}
      </g>
    </svg>
  );
};

export default Map;
```

Answer (score 0):

## Make sure `d` is defined and value has length

```
fill={color(d && d.value && d.value.length ? d.value[0].value : 0)}
```

If you ever find the error "Cannot read property [something] of undefined" you have tried to call something inside a variable that is undefined.

Comment: Using optional chaining: `fill={d?.value?.[0]?.value || 0}`